# Word for breaking the fast on Ramadan days

Tags: word-usage

What is the English word used for describing the 'breaking the fast' in the month of Ramadan ?

Comment: You're not really asking for an English word, are you?

Comment: This has nothing to do with English.

Comment: Out of idle curiosity... there another separate name for the first daytime meal after Ramadan ends: Eid ul-Fitr or something, right? I don't suppose that's what you were asking about? I had the misfortune of deciding to go to a buffet on that day one year. Huge crowd.

Comment: @Robusto: there -could- be a purely English term for it, and the OP doesn't know if there is one or not.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not asking for an English word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper word [would be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramadan#Iftar):

> **Iftar**: Muslims all around the world will abstain from food and drink, through fasting, from dawn to sunset. At sunset, the family will gather the fast-breaking meal known as Iftar.

The term in English however, would be "breakfast." Although the term is not commonly used in this fashion, "breakfast" has the meaning of breaking your nightly fast, and in the same way, can be used to mean breaking a longer fast. Webster's dictionary gives:

> A meal after fasting.

Comment: Yea. I browsed the link before asking here. I think, Iftar is an Arabic word rather than English. Can I call it as 'fast-breaking meal', but it is not a single word. What you think ?

Comment: Last time, the term "break-fast" was also used for breaking a fast. I think, if you used, "break-fast", it would be fine.

Comment: Will the people get confuse between 'breakfast' and 'break-fast'

Comment: Not if you explain. Say something like, "I am going to have my breakfast, that is, I am going to break my fast."

Comment: Well, there *will* be confusion. There isn't a single word that properly translates to iftar, and it is more commonly referred to as the "fast-breaking meal" in English media.

Comment: @Muhammed Rauf K - Well...only in the same way that "Ramadan" is. We don't use the same alphabet as Arabic does, so any English rendering is going to be imperfect (hence all the confusion over how to spell Khadaffi's name). I'm guessing the above rendering that Thursagen found is the generally accepted one for English.

Comment: FWIW, Jews understand "break-fast" for the meal at the end of Yom Kippur (and other fast days) and I've never heard it called anything else.  Pronounce it "break-fast", with the long vowel, not the usual "brekfast" pronunciation (sorry I don't know IPA).

Comment: @Thursagen, can you give a link for your Webster's citation? http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/break-fast?show=0&t=1312234248 doesn't list a hyphenated word "break-fast", nor does it give a sense other than the one restricted to the *morning* meal.

Answer (score 5):

On Google I found some instances of "Ramadan breakfast".

Answer (score 4):

**Iftar** is how you say it in English, as straight a borrowing as possible, with no translation. 'Breakfast', though it literally means breaking a fast, refers to the daily morning meal and is not used to replace 'iftar'. One might say during Iftar that one is breaking a fast but never that the event -is- 'breakfast'.

Answer (score 3):

Actually people use fast-breaking or breaking a fast for the same, but the most common used word is *iftar* which is an Arabic word with two meanings: *fast breaking meal* and *breaking a fast*.

The party given at the time of fast-breaking is known as *Iftar-Party*.

Answer (score 1):

Iftar means the breaking of the daily fast during Ramadam. 
It occurs on a daily basis, whereas the big celebration of Eid ul-fits is held to celebrate the end of the entire month long fast of Ramadam.
Hope this explains!?

Comment: This answer has already been given.